# Como cambiar de color un Jbutton

Tags: java, java-swing

Por alguna razón cuando cambio de color del Jbutton con el método .setBackGround(...) se cambia de color únicamente el borde, como en el caso de la imagen, donde estoy dando la instrucción de cambio de color a Rojo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que todo el botón sea de tal color al aplicarle el siguiente método

```
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evento) {
        ultimoBotonSeleccionado = (JButton) evento.getComponent();
        if (ultimoBotonSeleccionado.isEnabled() == true) {
            ultimoBotonSeleccionado.setBackground(COLOR_TITULO);
            ultimoBotonSeleccionado.setForeground(COLOR_FONDO);     
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es por el tema visual "**Aqua Look & Feel**", te recomiendo cambiarlo en la clase principal.

Por ejemplo al de windows:  `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");`